Why is "resonance" in these circuits exactly 41.1Hz?
Below is a series resonance simulation where we have 3 circuits with the same components just differing voltage frequencies. The middle circuit has an astoundingly large voltage peak compared to the other 2.

My question:
This resonance is when the impedance of all the components “lines up”. Why is this point mathematically 41.1HZ exactly and what does it mean for impedance to line up (the voltage in this middle circuit is so massive comapred to the others for some reason)?
Subquestion:
Why is voltage (green) lower than current in ONLY in the first one (aka the left most graph on bottom) but not others? It was my assumption that impedance shifts the waves along the x - axis and does not affect the peak amplitude, so this seems to be an incorrect assumption.

Have you actually tried calculating it?

The resonant frequency of an LC circuits is $f = 1/(2\pi\sqrt{LC})$. With $L = 1\textrm{H}$ and $C=15\mu\textrm{F}$ $f = 41.09\textrm{Hz}$.

The impedance of the inductor $Z_L$ is $i\omega L$. The impedance of the capacitor $Z_C$ is $1/(i\omega C)$. Remember that $1/i = -i$. This means that at some point $Z_C = -Z_L$, and the impedance of the RLC series combinations becomes just R.
At this frequency you get maximum current through the RLC circuit, and maximum voltage across any individual component (but the voltages across the L and C are $\pi$ out of phase so their voltages sum to 0).
For 15 uF and 1 H, this happens when
$$i\omega(1\ H) = -\frac{1}{i\omega(15\ \mu F)}$$
$$(i\omega)^2 = \frac{-1}{(1\ H)(15\ \mu F)}$$
$$-\omega^2=\frac{-1}{(15\times10^{-6}\ s^2)}$$
$$\omega \approx 258.2\ s^{-1}$$
and since $f=\omega/(2\pi)$,
$$ f \approx 41.1\ {\rm Hz}$$

Okay makes sense, but why would the voltage be so large, at recounace the phase shifting should calncel out. How does that affect the maximum voltage?

@ThePhoton voltage across L and C is not maximum at resonance, when R is present. Their peaks are kind of split wrt the resonance frequency for the current.

@user15755358, for each individual component, the voltage  is just $I \times Z$. If $I$ has a strong peak but $Z$ only changes gradually, the peak voltage will happen where $I$ peaks. But Peltio is right, there is actually a slight split in the voltage peaks between the capacitor and the inductor due to the opposite slopes of |Z| vs f for the two components..

The higher the Q, the closer the VL and VC peaks get to the resonant frequency, and the lower will be the voltage drop on the resistor. Equivalently, the higher the Q, the higher must be the voltage peaks across the reactive components.

@Peltio, sure. The way you get higher Q is to reduce R. Reduce R to 0 and the peak current ampitude goes to infinity.

This is an unexpectedly interesting question because it points out how 'resonant frequency' can have different meanings for different people or contexts.
You mention a voltage, but you do not say which voltage you are graphing. If you look at your series network as a two-port, with the input on the left and the output to the right, it is the capacitor voltage $V_C$ you are talking about. The answer is that its peak does NOT happen exactly at the same frequency of the peak in the current I (and therefore, the peak in the resistor voltage $V_R$).
We can see that the transfer functions $V_R/V_{\text{in}}$, $V_C/V_{\text{in}}$ and $V_L/V_{\text{in}}$ differ from each other not only for a scale factor but also from the presence of an additional factor $s$ or $1/s$.
$$\begin{align}
V_C &= \frac{1}{s} \ 1/C \ I \\
V_R &= R \ I \\ 
V_L &= s \  L \ I.
\end{align}$$
This means that one transfer function has an additional pole in the origin, while the other has a zero. This changes the shape of the transfer function, shifting the position in frequency where the peak is.

So, if you are referring to the peak in $V_C$, then its peak is NOT in
$$f = \frac{1}{2\ \pi \ \sqrt{L \ C}}.$$
(I don't have the time right now to type the exact formula, but you can find it with a bit of calculus). The frequency above is sometimes called the phase resonant frequency of the circuit and the amplitude resonant frequency for $V_R$, but it is not the amplitude resonant frequency for $V_C$ (or $V_L$).
The difference is usually small and becomes negligible for high values of Q.
As a matter of fact, for your circuit values with R=10 ohms, the peaks are almost (but NOT exactly) all coincident, but note how big are the voltages across capacitor and inductor: nearly 3.3kV!

As for your follow-up question in the comments, "Why is the maximum voltage so big?" the answer is that, in general, it isn't. It is only when the $Q$ of the oscillator is high that the reactances of the capacitor and inductor are much bigger than the resistance $R$ so that for the same current $I$ in the series, their voltage happen to be much bigger than $V_R$.
P.S.
It does not make any sense to compare the amplitude of the voltage and current waveforms in the graphs since they are not in the same physical unit.
